# Question about the definition of representability of a quadratic form

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, quadratic-forms

Say I have an integral quadratic form $q$ on $\mathbb{Z}^r$ and another integral binary quadratic form $\tilde{q}$. What does it mean for $q$ to primitively represent $\tilde{q}$? I can't seem to find the definition anywhere. Of course $q$ primitively represents an integer $m$ if there exists a primitive element $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}^r$ such that $q(\alpha)=m$, but I'm not sure what it means to represent another quadratic form (especially when the other quadratic form is not defined on the same amount of variables!).

Comment: I added something about page 18. Not widely known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take the Gram matrix, which is generally taken to be the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives. Let $A$ be the Gram matrix for your $q,$ and $B$ be the Gram matrix for the other one. Representation is a rectangular matrix $P$ such that $$ P^T A P = B.   $$ Primitive representation is if the GCD of all the entries of $P$ is $1.$ Where are you reading about this?

The case with which you are familiar is when $P$ is a column vector and $B$ is a 1 by 1 matrix, that is, a number.

On page 18, remark 35, you need Estes and Pall (1973), which I put at [TERNARY](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/forms.html). The principal forms are the squares in the class group. The spinor kernel is the fourth powers in the group. Your $\bar{s}(D)$ is the number of spinor genera per genus, which is the same as the number of squares divided by the number of fourth powers.

Comment: Oh great! I'm reading this paper by Kani: http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~kani/papers/jacob8.pdf. I'm a geometer, so this is the first time I've come across the need to use quadratic forms in depth.

Comment: Awesome, that makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Comment: @RobertAuffarth, there is a quadratic forms conference every few years at Talca.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about that, I'll have to look it up. I know Ricardo Baeza is there, and I've been in touch with several algebraic geometers from there.

Comment: You got a page number in mind?

Comment: Section 3 on page 5

Comment: Also some Icazas are there. There used to be an Irish q.f. guy, can't recall the name.

Comment: http://inst-mat.utalca.cl/html/nosotros/profesores.html

Comment: Have you ever visited Talca?

Comment: I got invited last time but no travel support, and I could not afford it. Would have been nice. Note that forms representing forms got a big boost after Ellenberg and Venkatesh, later cleaned up by Schulze-Pillot

Comment: Thanks a lot Will, and hope to see you down here in Chile some day!

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment you posted, I just saw it.